# Why does sudo not remember the password when executed in a script with redirected streams?

Tags: sudo

**robot**:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo echo apple
sudo cat << EOF
banana
EOF
```

**command prompt**:

```
$ sudo true
[sudo] password for vb:
$ ./robot
apple
banana
$ ./robot > /dev/null
$ ./robot &> /dev/null
[sudo] password for vb:
```

Why sudo(1) asks for password when stdout and stderr are redirected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sudo remembers your password (your authentication) for some time so you do not have to enter the password for multiple commands in quick succession.

The duration is controlled by the `timestamp_timeout` statement in the `/etc/sudoers` file. Read `man sudoers` for more information.

More interessting is the question *how* your authentication is remembered. Everytime you use sudo, sudo will create a file in the directory `/var/run/sudo/username` (Ubuntu 10.04). The filename is taken from your current terminal (or tty). That means sudo remembers your authentication on a per terminal basis. If you switch to another terminal, sudo will not remember that you just used sudo on the previous terminal.

Demonstration:

Use sudo:

```
$ sudo echo foo
[sudo] password for lesmana: 
foo
```

See file created in `/var/run/sudo/username`:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/run/sudo/lesmana
total 0
-rw------- 1 root lesmana  0 2011-04-25 16:56 1
```

Note that this sudo did not ask for password. The file is named `1` because I ran the sudo command from tty (or pts) number 1. use the `tty` command to see your tty name.

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/1
```

Now switch to another terminal:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/2
```

Use sudo in this terminal.

```
$ sudo echo bar
[sudo] password for lesmana: 
bar
```

Note that it asks for a password.

See file created in `/var/run/sudo/username`:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/run/sudo/lesmana
total 0
-rw------- 1 root lesmana 0 2011-04-25 16:56 1
-rw------- 1 root lesmana 0 2011-04-25 16:57 2 # <-- new
```

Now switch to a virtual console.

```
$ tty
/dev/tty/1
```

Use sudo:

```
$ sudo echo baz
[sudo] password for lesmana: 
baz
```

See file created in `/var/run/sudo/username`:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/run/sudo/lesmana
total 0
-rw------- 1 root lesmana 0 2011-04-25 16:56 1
-rw------- 1 root lesmana 0 2011-04-25 16:57 2
-rw------- 1 root lesmana 0 2011-04-25 16:58 tty1 # <-- new
```

Now let's try that using your shell script. I used the same robot script as in the question text.

```
$ ./robot
apple
banana
```

No password prompt because I used the first terminal in which sudo still remembers my password.

See the file updated in `/var/run/sudo/username`:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/run/sudo/lesmana
total 0
-rw------- 1 root lesmana 0 2011-04-25 17:01 1 # <-- timestamp update
-rw------- 1 root lesmana 0 2011-04-25 16:57 2
-rw------- 1 root lesmana 0 2011-04-25 16:58 tty1
```

Now let's try the script with redirection:

```
$ ./robot > foo
[sudo] password for lesmana:
```

Note that sudo asked for password.

Check `/var/run/sudo/username`:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/run/sudo/lesmana
total 0
-rw------- 1 root lesmana 0 2011-04-25 17:01 1
-rw------- 1 root lesmana 0 2011-04-25 16:57 2
-rw------- 1 root lesmana 0 2011-04-25 16:58 tty1
-rw------- 1 root lesmana 0 2011-04-25 17:02 unknown # <-- new
```

See that `unknown` file. For whatever reason sudo is no longer able to determine the terminal when executed in a script with redirected streams. That is why sudo asks you for your password.

Note that on your system sudo asked for password only after redirecting both stdout and stderr. On my system (ubuntu 10.04) sudo asked for password when I redirected stdout. I have no idea why there is this difference.

Note also that you can make sudo forget your authentication immediately with the command `sudo -k`. This will only forget the authentication for the terminal where the command was issued.

Comment: I use Debian 6.0.1. On this system the directory where sudo(1) stores passwords is /var/lib/sudo/vb/, and I notice no "tty?" nor "unknown" files here. Only "0", "1", "2", and "3". I never heard about tty(1) previously so I tried the following: 1) add "tty" to the robot script; 2) ./robot &> tempfile; 3) cat tempfile. The strange thing was that tempfile contain "/dev/pts/3" line. So, why "sudo is no longer able to determine the terminal when executed in a script with redirected streams."? Is it a bug?

Comment: @vladimirbarbarosh: I also added a `tty` line in the `robot` script, and on my system it was also able to correctly name the tty. I have no idea why sudo is not able to determine that on my system. I also have no idea why sudo seems to have the correct tty name on your sysem, yet still asks for an password as if it a differnet tty. Perhaps it is a bug, I just don't know whether it is on my system, or on your system, or on both.

Comment: The problem lies here: `sudo &> /dev/null < /dev/null`. Everything ok for `sudo &> /dev/null`. I ask the question on [sudo maillist](http://www.sudo.ws/mailman/listinfo/sudo-users). As soon as I found the answer I will post it here. Just now I consider this as a _bug_.

Answer (score 2):

It reads from and writes to `/dev/tty`, which always connects to the current tty/pty.

Comment: This is a security feature to prevent, for example, brute force attacks.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that "sudo -A" is the only choice to circumvent this.

Comment: @Amazed: I doubt that. A bruteforcer process could allocate a pty in two lines of code. It seems to me that it's just to allow the user to redirect all output and not have it messed up by the password prompt.